# Issues with SQL Connection from an IIS ASP.NET container

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, iis, containers

Background:
I'm porting over applications to docker containers using the latest 4.8 ASP net container. They all use SQL Server connections.

App1: Framework 4.8, no issues at all.
App2: Framework 4.6.2, can't establish a connection to the SQL Server at all.

Here's the connection string:

`<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=172.31.0.2; Initial Catalog=Integ_Catalog;  User ID=MYUSER; Password=Pa55W0rd; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=120" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

From within the container, I've ran Powershell to verify the connection string is 100% working. I've updated dapper to the latest version hoping that would help. Any ideas what to try?

Trace

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
```

*** Update ***

When the app was within the same AWS VPC as the DB, the calls would fail. But when they are in a different VPC, it would work. This makes no sense, you'd think it would be the other way around. Networking on the DB, App/Host and within the VPC look fine.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: If it works in .NET Framework 4.8 but not 4.6.2 I'd be suspicious of TLS 1.2 connection issues. Confirm that app2 is actually targeting and built for .NET Framework 4.6.2 (4.6.2 and later support TLS 1.2) and look for any references to `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType` that may be trying to configure SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0 or TLS 1.1 connections (all of which are deprecated).

Comment: .NET frame differences shouldn't cause any error. It could be something else, it would be ideal to enable tracing and get the stack trace.

Comment: I added the trace, thanks.

Comment: Check that TCP/IP is enabled on the server. (In SQL Server Configuration Manager), or anything else (firewall) that might be blocking your connection. The client thinks it cannot find the server, and the error 0x80004005 typically relates to some form of denial. Any chance that there's a connection encryption difference between the two?

Comment: It more sounds like a compatibility issue becasue if that was a schannel issue, the server should return error like" can't find common alogorithmn". Besides, if it is a network issue, .net 4.8 should fail.

Comment: can you share relevant bits of Powershell script you tested the connectivity with? I would also try adding `Net=dbmssocn` to your connection string to force TCP/IP

Comment: @timur I tried adding `Network Library=DBMSSOCN;` but it didn't seem to help. Only test I did was a simple connection open, like `$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $connectionString
$sqlConnection.Open()`. Curious is there is something special being inside a container that is is breaking it because it works just fine on a regular instance.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to move app over to an outside VPC, why? The world may never know :)

Comment: What was your routing and firewall configuration?

Comment: It was wide open

Answer (score 0):

You need to add IIS_USR in SQL Server and need to give permission to access the Database